# How to relocate an element in one array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I took this interview question and I failed, so I'm here to not fail again!

I have an array of int with size 16 and a 5 < givenIndex < 10.

I have to take the element in this index a print every possible array (there are 16) by moving the element at givenIndex through every position in array and pushing rest of elements.

For example:

```cpp
int array[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
int givenIndex = 6;
```

Since `array[givenIndex] = 7`, I need to move 7 to every possible position and print that array.

```cpp
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

[1,7,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

[1,2,7,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

And that's for 16 cases.

What I was trying was:

```cpp
for(int i = 0;i<16;i++){
        array[i] = array[indexInsercion]
        if (i<indexInsert){
            //right shift
            array[i] = array[i+1]
        }else if(i == indexInsert){
            //no shift
        }else{
            //left shift
            array[i] = array[i-1]
        }
    }
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: What result are you expecting? Are you trying to print these arrays as you iterate? Are you trying to generate a collection of these arrays?

Comment: please post a [mcve] of your code. Eg what is `indexInsercion` ?

Comment: First you need to [`rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) so the desired number is at the front. Then you can [`swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) the desired element with the next element repeately to have it "step forward".

Comment: hint: very often when a task says "do something with an array" you do not actually have to do something with the array. Here you need not shift elements to get the desired output, when it is just about printing on the screen

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Cool! I'll try that approach

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: You don't need rotate unless the resulting arrays have to be printed in a specific order. But rotating is simpler so I'd do it anyway.

Comment: When I ask a question like this in an interview I'm not doing it to see the applicant code. I'm doing it to see them think. I want to see the problem solving process. My recommendation is to not jump immediately into code. Come up with a plan and then code.

Comment: My comment was wrong but the other ones are good. This is a very underspecified problem. There are few approaches. Generating permutations, mutating the input, producing the output. I don't think it's possible to be answered in one correct way. Perhaps that was even the point of the question. Like a classic "FizzBuzz".

Comment: I think that the point is that index of each element in array changes when I move the element of givenIndex

Comment: Perhaps you failed because "print every possible array" does not say, anywhere in it, that you have to actually ***change the array*** and then print it. This can be done simply by making repeated passes over the array, and just making the adjustment on the fly, printing the selected element in the right position, instead of its current position. This is fairly simple, and trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expectation is to just print the elements of array in the given order:

Keep the track of current index of array element to be print, say `indx` -

- If the position of current element processing is equal to row number then
  print the element at `givenIndex`.
- If `indx` is equal to `givenIndex` skip it and print `indx + 1` element, otherwise print element at `indx` and increase `indx` by `1`.

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 16> array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    std::size_t givenIndex = 6;

    for (std::size_t i = 0, indx = 0; i < array.size(); indx = 0, ++i) {
        std::cout << '[';

        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < array.size(); ++j) {
            if (j == i) {
                std::cout << array[givenIndex] << ',';
                continue;
            }

            if (indx == givenIndex) {
                ++indx;
            }

            std::cout << array[indx++] << ',';
        }

        std::cout << ']';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,7,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,7,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,7,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,7,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,7,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,7,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,7,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,7,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,7,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,7,]
```

If the expectation is to alter the order of elements in the array and then print the array:

First move the element at `givenIndex` to the `0`<sup>th</sup> index of array and then -

- Print array
- In every iteration swap the current element with its next element in the array and print it.

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void print_array (std::array<int, 16>& array) {
    std::cout << '[';
    for (std::size_t indx = 0; indx < array.size(); ++indx) {
        std::cout << array[indx] << ',';
    }
    std::cout << ']';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void rearrange_array_elem (std::array<int, 16>& array, std::size_t givenIndx) {
    // move the element at givneIndx to first position in array
    for (std::size_t j = givenIndx; j > 0; --j) {
        std::swap (array[j], array[j - 1]);
    }

    // print array
    print_array (array);

    for (std::size_t indx = 0; indx < array.size() - 1; ++indx) {
        // swap current element with its next element
        std::swap (array[indx], array[indx + 1]);
        print_array (array);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 16> array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    std::size_t givenIndex = 6;

    rearrange_array_elem (array, givenIndex);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,7,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,7,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,7,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,7,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,7,12,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,7,13,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,7,14,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,7,15,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,7,16,]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,7,]
```

Comment: Thanks! It was precise

Comment: The first loop with `std::swap`s could be replaced with `std::rotate`.

Answer (score 3):

We can only guess what the interviewer expected to see. If I was the interviewer I would like to see that you keep things simple. This is code I think one can expect to be written from scratch in an interview situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <size_t size>
void print_replaced(const std::array<int,size>& x,size_t index){
    for (int i=0;i<size;++i){
        for (int j=0;j<i;++j) {
            if (j == index) continue;
            std::cout << x[j] << " ";
        } 
        std::cout << x[index] << " ";
        for (int j=i;j<size;++j) {
            if (j == index) continue; 
            std::cout << x[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    std::array<int,16> x{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    print_replaced(x,6);
}
```

It is a first approach at the problem, with a loop that prints 16 different combinations of the array elements. Printing each line follows simple logic: We print all elements before the one that should be replaced, then the one that should be shuffled, then the remaining elements.

It is simple, but wrong. Its output is:

```
7 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 7 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 7 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 7 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 7 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 7 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 7 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 7 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 7 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 7 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 7 16
```

There is one line that appears twice and the last line is missing.

As an interviewer I would not be surprised that the first attempt does not produce correct output. I don't care about that. Thats not a minus. What I would care about is how you react on that. Do you know the next steps? Do you have a strategy to fix the wrong output? Or do you just panic because you didn't manage to write the correct code on the first attempt? This is what I would like to check in an interview and then thats the end of the exercise. I want to ask more different questions rather than giving you the time to fix all mistakes and write correct well tested code, because I know that this takes more time than we have in the interview.

I'll leave it to you to fix the above code ;)

Comment: I had those same two bugs too! I completely agree with that last part of your answer as well. The process is more important than the perfect answer.

Comment: I tried to not panic but it is hard when you think there's other person who probably smashes Leetcode. Thanks you anyway, I fixed code :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick stab at it. Basically just keep track of where the given index should go and print it there as well as skip the original position it would be in.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[16] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 };
    int givenIndex = 6;

    for (int p = 0; p <= 16; ++p)
    {
        if (p != givenIndex)
        {
            std::cout << "[";
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            {
                if (i == p)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << ",";
                    }
                    std::cout << array[givenIndex];
                }
                if (array[i] != array[givenIndex])
                {
                    if (i > 0 || p == 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << ",";
                    }
                    std::cout << array[i];
                }
            }
            if (p == 16)
            {
                std::cout << "," << array[givenIndex];
            }
            std::cout << "]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,7,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,7,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,7,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,7,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,7,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,7,12,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,7,13,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,7,14,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,7,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,7,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,7]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer! I'm trying to figure out why when givenIndex = 5 it prints only 13 values. For example for random numbers: [,1,9,8,5,5,6,9,5,8,0,8,6,8]

Comment: Random numbers are a different problem. This code assumes the value at the given index will only appear once in the array, and `if (array[i] != array[givenIndex])` is what prevents it from printing. A more robust solution might be to split up the inner loop to print the value before where the givenIndex will appear in that line, print the givenIndex, then print the rest of the line. It looks like a simple problem but has some interesting edge cases. I like it as an interview style question.